# How to get out of redirection loop with mod_rewrite on query parameters?

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I need to implement redirection rule depending on the query string. The query string will 
contain four parameters but they can take variable positions, like

```
www.a.com/whatever?w=1&x=2&y=3&z=india_en
www.a.com/whatever?x=2&w=1&y=3&z=india_en
```

which will get redirected to

```
www.a.com/whatever?x=2&w=1&y=3&z=a006
```

Beside these I need check for another parameter `sid`. If `sid` is present in the query string then redirection will not happen.

I've wrote the redirection rule the following way (for the first part of course):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^w=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=MY_W:w=%1] [NC,C]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^x=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=MY_X:x=%1] [NC,C]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^y=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=MY_Y:y=%1] [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^z=india_en$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=MY_Z:z=a006] [C]
RewriteRule ^(/whatever)$ http://www.a.com$1?%{ENV:MY_W}&%{ENV:MY_X}&%{ENV:MY_Y}&%{ENV:MY_Z} [L,R=permanent]
```

But I'm getting redirection loop with innumerable ampersand at the end like

**input:** `http://www.a.com/whatever?w=1&x=2&y=3&z=india_en`

**output:** `http://www.a.com/whatever?w=1&x=2&y=3&z=india_en&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&`

How to get out of that loop?

Comment: Have a look on [ask], especially also on formatting code. You forgot to mention the probably most important tag for your quesiton, "mod-rewrite".

Comment: Missed the vital tag. Thanks Ranon.

Answer (score 0):

```
#don't rewrite if parameters are already in the right order
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^w=(.*)x=(.*)y=(.*)z=(.*)$
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^w=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=MY_W:w=%1] [NC,C]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^x=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=MY_X:x=%1] [NC,C]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^y=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=MY_Y:y=%1] [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^z=india_en$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=MY_Z:z=a006] [C]
RewriteRule ^(/whatever)$ http://www.a.com$1?%{ENV:MY_W}&%{ENV:MY_X}&%{ENV:MY_Y}&%{ENV:MY_Z} [L,R=permanent]
```

Comment: redirection loop is still occurring.